# Nagios Notification Suppression For No Ping Host Services

Tags: service, dependencies, nagios

I've got numerous services on public internet hosts that are being monitored. The hosts are not pingable, so I use a no-check host definition with standard service checks.

In an effort to have intelligent notifications, preventing notifications when upstream networks are down, I have set parents for all hosts as appropriate. This maps out correctly, but I'm still flooded with alerts when a router goes down and takes out down stream services.

Nagios === RouterHostA === RouterHostB === No Ping Host w/services.

What do I need to do to prevent notifications for the services when RouterHostB is down. I presume that the issue is the no-check hosts staying up, but I thought Nagios would stop all checks on hosts and their service when the parent router goes down.

It kills me every time I get a 200 Problem and then another 200 Restored text messages.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected the issue is that the no ping/check host stays up, so the service check issues a notification. It is necessary to have the host check fail and show the host down. I was able to do this with a check_tcp to the service's port. It's

```
define host{
    host_name       No Ping Host
    alias           www.xyz.tld
    address         www.xyz.tld
    check_command   check_tcp!443 
    parents         RouterHostB
    }

define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               No Ping Host
    service_description     HTTPS_URL
    check_command           check_https_url!/index.html!serialnumber!
    }
```

It's not ideal, but it seems that it is the best available option.